# Verbal Offer received; should I continue interviewing or wait for the written offer?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-offer

I have a verbal offer but not a written offer and am not sure whether I should proceed to an onsite interview at another company.

Since I have not received the written offer yet, should I go ahead and interview with the other company (e.g. make travel arrangement)? Or should I just accept the risk and assume that I will get the written offer?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: So lets say I make plans to interview at the other Company next Tueday and get the offer on Monday. Should I inform the other company that I got another offer and still go to the onsite?

Comment: @intervuewguy I addressed that on the comments under my answer. If you receive it and *signed it* that same Monday it would be courteous to contact the other company and cancel so nobody wastes time and resources.

Answer (score 6):

> Or should I just accept the risk and assume that I will get the written offer?

I *strongly* suggest you don't assume anything here, and **keep your options open until the moment you get a written offer and *sign* it.**

In other words, attend to this and other interviews you can until you receive and decide to take an offer. Only after that proceed to cancel any pending interviews you have in a professional way.

Comment: But lets say I get the written offer the day of the other onsite interview. Should I still go to that interview and tell them about my decision to accept the other offer? I don't want to waste their time or money.

Comment: That sounds hypothetical... anyways. The moment you receive a written offer, and the moment you decide you want it and actually go and *sign it*, that is the moment you should reach and cancel the interview, but not before.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: Or maybe reschedule the onsite so that there is enough time to receive the written offer?

Comment: @intervuewguy I feel you are over-thinking this one... just keep going to interviews until you get an offer and sign it. After that moment, given you already are committed to another company, it would be courteous and professional to cancel your remaining interviews, if any.... who knows, perhaps you never get the written offer, and if you cancel the other interview you are missing that chance